# How to handle empty cells that pandas does not recognize?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am data preprocessing using nlp techniques. When I try to remove the URL links from the dataframe, those rows that had URL links become blank entries or non-ascii characters. These blanks are seen in the excel file when I download the dataframe as csv. However, when I implement the following code

```
df.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True) OR
df['columnName'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

this code outputs there are no NULL or empty values in the dataframe but in reality there are. How to deal with this situation? I want to delete all such empty rows

Comment: `df.values` and see if the cells are indeed empty strings: `''` vs `' '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just using `str.strip` before `replace`

```
df['columnName']=df['columnName'].str.strip().replace('',np.nan)
```

Working around example

```
s=pd.Series(['   ','llllll'])
s.str.strip().replace('',np.nan)
0       NaN
1    llllll
dtype: object
```

Comment: @user11035754 yw :-) happy coding

Comment: I tried this but this TypeError has occurred. `TypeError: replace() argument 2 must be str, not float`